# syntax to call external file for testing purposes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a long JSON file (about 10000 lines) which I want to use for testing purposes (rather than hitting the external server everytime: `response_test.json`

What is the proper syntax to substitute in the controller the httparty post

```
  @result = HTTParty.post(
    'https://test.com/search', 
    :body => [...]
```

with a reference to the file? and where should this file be ideally stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON mocks files are ideally stored in the `fixtures` directory. If you're using RSpec, you can store the file in `spec/fixtures/mocks`.

#### Update:

Here are the steps to take if you want to mock API calls in your test environment:

1. Install the [webmock gem](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock)
2. Add the following to configure webmock in `spec/spec_helper` to disable all external API calls. Webmock will throw an error and suggest how to stub the respective API calls.

   ```
   # spec/spec_helper.rb

   require 'webmock/rspec'
   WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)
   ```
3. Then, before you make the API call in your test, stub your request to return `response_test.json` as the body

   ```
   stub_request(:post, 'https://test.com/search')
     .to_return(headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json; charset=utf-8' },
                body: response_test.json)

   result = HTTParty.post(
     'https://test.com/search',
     :body => [...]

   # Assert that result matches some value in the JSON content      
   expect(result.some_attribute).to eq(some_value)
   ```

To clean this up a bit, you can also extract the `stub_request` block to a method and call the method before the API call.

Comment: I am actually wanting to use a JSON file in lieu of `@result`, not submit a json file to the API `(rather than hitting the external server everytime)` ...  I can read and load a file `test_data = File.read("uploads/response_test.json") but rails handles it as a string.

Comment: Ha, alright that wasn't clear enough. If I understand you correctly, you would like to mock the API call? I've just updated the answer to include how to mock an API call using webmock. Does that answer your question?

Comment: yes it does.  Interesting approach the webmock gem.  In the meantime, I found another (more traditional) way... `@test_data = File.read("uploads/response_test.json")  @result = JSON.parse(@test_data)`

Answer (score 1):

```
json = File.read('fixtures/my_json.json')
json_parsed = JSON.parse(json)
@result = HTTParty.post('https://test.com/search',:body => json_parsed.to_json)
```